# CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth adding user using modal

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, ion-auth

I am new to Ion Auth codeigniter library. Now I am making a custom bootstrap form to add a user using modal but I always get errors. Any help would be much appreciated. The modal is inside the userList.php view that displays all registered users.

Controller: Users.php

```
function create_user()
    {
        $this->data['title'] = "Create User";

        if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in() || !$this->ion_auth->is_admin())
        {
            redirect('auth', 'refresh');
        }

        $tables = $this->config->item('tables','ion_auth');
        $identity_column = $this->config->item('identity','ion_auth');
        $this->data['identity_column'] = $identity_column;

        // validate form input
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_fname_label'), 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_lname_label'), 'required');
        if($identity_column!=='email')
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('identity',$this->lang->line('create_user_validation_identity_label'),'required|is_unique['.$tables['users'].'.'.$identity_column.']');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_email_label'), 'required|valid_email');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_email_label'), 'required|valid_email|is_unique[' . $tables['users'] . '.email]');
        }
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_phone_label'), 'trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('company', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_company_label'), 'trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_password_label'), 'required|min_length[' . $this->config->item('min_password_length', 'ion_auth') . ']|max_length[' . $this->config->item('max_password_length', 'ion_auth') . ']|matches[password_confirm]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_confirm', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_password_confirm_label'), 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
        {
            $email    = strtolower($this->input->post('email'));
            $identity = ($identity_column==='email') ? $email : $this->input->post('identity');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');

            $additional_data = array(
                'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
                'last_name'  => $this->input->post('last_name'),
                'company'    => $this->input->post('company'),
                'phone'      => $this->input->post('phone'),
            );

            var_dump($first_name);
        }
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true && $this->ion_auth->register($identity, $password, $email, $additional_data))
        {
            // check to see if we are creating the user
            // redirect them back to the admin page
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
            redirect("auth", 'refresh');
        }
        else
        {
            // display the create user form
            // set the flash data error message if there is one
            $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : ($this->ion_auth->errors() ? $this->ion_auth->errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message')));

            $this->data['first_name'] = array(
                'name'  => 'first_name',
                'id'    => 'first_name',
                'type'  => 'text',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('first_name'),
            );
            $this->data['last_name'] = array(
                'name'  => 'last_name',
                'id'    => 'last_name',
                'type'  => 'text',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('last_name'),
            );
            $this->data['identity'] = array(
                'name'  => 'identity',
                'id'    => 'identity',
                'type'  => 'text',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('identity'),
            );
            $this->data['email'] = array(
                'name'  => 'email',
                'id'    => 'email',
                'type'  => 'text',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('email'),
            );
            $this->data['company'] = array(
                'name'  => 'company',
                'id'    => 'company',
                'type'  => 'text',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('company'),
            );
            $this->data['phone'] = array(
                'name'  => 'phone',
                'id'    => 'phone',
                'type'  => 'text',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('phone'),
            );
            $this->data['password'] = array(
                'name'  => 'password',
                'id'    => 'password',
                'type'  => 'password',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('password'),
            );
            $this->data['password_confirm'] = array(
                'name'  => 'password_confirm',
                'id'    => 'password_confirm',
                'type'  => 'password',
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('password_confirm'),
            );

            $this->_render_page('userList', $this->data);
        }
    }
```

View: userList.php

```
<div class="modal fade" id="add-user" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-default">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 id="modal-user-profile" class="modal-title">Add User</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                <?php echo form_open('users/create_user', ['class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'form']); ?>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="first_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <?php echo form_input($first_name);?>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <?php echo form_password(['name' => 'password', 'id' => 'password', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Password']); ?>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <?php echo form_password(['name' => 'password_confirm', 'id' => 'password_confirm', 'class' => 'form-control', 'value' => set_value('password_confirm'), 'placeholder' => 'Confirm Password']); ?>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <?php echo form_input(['name' => 'email', 'id' => 'email', 'class' => 'form-control', 'value' => set_value('email'), 'placeholder' => 'Email']); ?>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Contact No</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <?php echo form_input(['name' => 'contact', 'id' => 'contact', 'class' => 'form-control', 'value' => set_value('contact'), 'placeholder' => 'Contact']); ?>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <label for="status" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Group</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select class="form-control" id="group">
                    <option>--</option>
                    <option>Admin</option>
                    <option>Client</option>
                    <option>BIR</option>
                </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <label for="status" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Status</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select class="form-control" id="status">
                    <option>--</option>
                    <option>Active</option>
                    <option>Inactive</option>
                </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default create-user">Create</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger create">Cancel</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What errors are you getting??
In your controller, Use this to verify your results

After query; 
echo $this->db->last_query();

var_dump($_POST);exit;

First check all the post data and the query and tell the errors you're getting

Comment: Thanks for the response but the issue is not about the post data. I tried to resolve but now form validation turn to false.